# Mobile Menu in Wordpress (Divi Theme) with Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Im working on a wordpress site for a client and i use the Divi theme. When you go down to tablet breakpoint and lower, i implemented a hamburger menu, you can check it out here:
http://tk.cavar-marketing.de/

Now there is one menu point "Leistungen" (services) where i need a submenu. My idea is, that when i click on "Leistungen", another fullwidth menu in different color comes from the left and covers the whole menu. For clarification i created an sketch in Photoshop:

[sketch of my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaBI5.jpg)

This is the current code:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">  

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a><a href="#">Home</a><a href="#">Unternehmen</a><a href="#">Leistungen</a><a href="#">Referenzen</a><a href="#">Karriere</a><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
</div>  

<div class="hamburgermenu">  

<div>  

<span class="hambi" style="font-size:24px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</span>
</div>  
>  
></div>  
>  
><script>  
>  
>function openNav() {  
>  
>  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";  
>  
>}  
>  
>function closeNav() {  
>  
>  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";  
>  
>}  
>  
></script>
```

I styled all the stuff in CSS, which code is not so important i guess?

Now how could i achieve what i need? I dont know much about JS, but i understand what the code does. Can you help me =)
Thanks and regards!

Comment: Doesn't the theme come with a built-in solution for that? Or are you required to do a custom implementation for some reason?

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for your comment. Sadly the built-in solution is not good. It looks shabby. I like these fullscreen menus that slide in from the side. =)

Comment: Alright, you need to add a click event handler to the `Leistungen` link that slides in the second menu. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Okay. So would this work?

<a href="#" onclick="openSubNav()">Leistungen</a>

I tried that alrdy with the existing function "openNav()" but it doesnt work. Do you know why? Im sorry, but im an absolute JS noob.

Comment: It should work like that in principle, yes. How exactly does it "not work"? Do you have a function called `openSubNav`? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks again for your help!

So i did the following:

1) I added a SubNav div with the id "mySubNav" and the class "subnav".
2) I gave it have a red background, so i can see if it works
3) I made the function "openSubNav", it looks like this:
function openSubNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySubnav").style.width = "100";
}
4) I added the onclick to the a link: 
<a href="#" onclick="openSubNav()">Leistungen</a>

But when i click nothing happens. There is also no console error. I tried if onclick="closeNav" would work and it worked. So it's either a problem with the

Comment: function or with the appearance of the subnav div. I guess it's the second. So is there a way to maybe let the function FIRST close the nav div (the blue one) and then open the red one? Thank again!

Comment: Setting width to `100` won't work, you need a unit like `100%`